# Использование данных полей ввода в запросе

Tags: 1с, запрос

Добрый день (вечер или утро)
**1С:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.13.219) нетиповая конфигурация**

Я разобрался, как использовать данные полей ввода в запросе для отчета, используя набор данных - объект. Просто, пишу необходимый код в обработчике нажатия клавиши формирования результата.  
А вот как использовать поля ввода, когда используем набор данных - запрос? Ведь там не нужно писать никакой код на форме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если отчёт на СКД - тогда там всё очень просто: в запросе указываете условия с необходимыми параметрами ("`ГДЕ Поставщик = &параметрПоставщик`"). Потом на вкладке "Параметры" редактора СКД снимаете с этих параметров галочку "Ограничение доступности" и потом на вкладке "Настройки" внизу тоже есть вкладка "Параметры", там выносите параметры или в быстрые настройки или в просто настройки. Так-же тут можно задать своим параметрам значения по умолчанию. И все эти параметры появятся на форме отчёта над самим отчётом.

Comment: спасибо, завтра попробую

Comment: Это все, конечно, здорово. Но я, например, делаю все вышеуказанное, создаю параметры начала и конца периода, делаю основную форму отчета, размещаю на нее два поля ввода даты. И как мне эти параметры связать с данными полей ввода?

Comment: Если вы делаете отчет на СКД, то создавать форму вовсе не обязательно, в СКД перейдите на закладку "Настройки", выберите вкладку "Параметры" и у каждого параметра поставьте галку "Включать в пользовательские настройки"

Comment: Думаю вам будет интересна [эта](http://knigibest.clan.su/load/kompjuternaja/programmirovanie/khrustaleva_e_ju_razrabotka_slozhnykh_otchetov_v_1s_predprijatii_8_sistema_komponovki_dannykh/14-1-0-774) книга

Comment: сделал все так:

![alt text][3]
![alt text][4]  

что получили:   
 
![alt text][2]

  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/huJyw.jpg
  [3]: http://i.imgur.com/1B6yX.jpg
  [4]: http://i.imgur.com/6L3lu.jpg

Comment: Откройте Настройки - там будет ваш период. [Тут](http://1cskd.ru/categories/) есть примеры работы с СКД

Comment: Пример кода из вышеупомянутой ссылки

    Процедура ПриОткрытии()
       ПараметрСКД = КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки.ПараметрыДанных.
                                     Элементы.Найти("ИмяПараметра")
       ПараметрСКД.Использование = Истина;
       ПараметрСКД.Значение  = Значение;
    КонецПроцедуры

Comment: @Егор Соколов, спасибо